# Showing multiple preload animations in a flexible multi-button form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Beginner front-end developer here.

I have 2 `choose file` buttons in a photo uploading form. I also have 2 `upload` buttons under each of them respectively, which process the uploading.

Now this form is flexible.

For example, you choose a file via the first `choose file` button but press the second `upload` button - the upload still works.

Or you choose 2 files (via both `choose file` buttons), pressing any of the `upload` buttons makes **both** files to upload.

---

My objective is to now show a loading animation in the cases above. I.e. show a loading animation around the first `choose file` button even if the second `upload` button was clicked and vice versa. Or around both `choose file` buttons regardless of which `upload` button was clicked.

I've gotten to the following so far:

```
var input = $("input[type=file]");

$("[id^=Btn]").click(function() {
  if (input.filter(function(index, el) {
    return el.files.length
  }) === 2) {
    $("[id^=loader], [id^=spinner]").show();
    $("[id^=Btn]").hide();
  } else {
      if (input.eq(0)[0].files.length && !input.eq(1)[0].files.length
         || input.eq(1)[0].files.length && !input.eq(0)[0].files.length) { 
           $("[id^=loader]:eq(0), [id^=spinner]:eq(0)").show();
           $("[id^=Btn]:eq(0)").hide();           
      } else {
        if (input.eq(1)[0].files.length) {
          $("[id^=loader]:eq(1), [id^=spinner]:eq(1)").show();
          $("[id^=Btn]:eq(1)").hide();
        }
      }
  }    
});
```

This was after some help from some experts at SO. I'm still struggling to cover all the bases though. Specifically, the above snippet is unable to show both preload animations *together* if 2 files were uploading simultaneously. How do I tweak it? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: _"Specifically, the above snippet is unable to show both preload animations together if 2 files were uploading simultaneously."_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? The first `if` statement should render both animations. Do the `<input type="file">` elements have `multiple` attribute set?

Comment: I have tried multiple times to make both loading animations run together if 2 files were uploading simultaneously. The animation only runs around the choose files whose upload button is clicked, i.e. if i have uploaded 2 files in the respected fields and then click on the second upload button then the animation only runs around the 2nd upload field.

Comment: Can you include HTML at Question?

Comment: Here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/shahz/2j8jfkf5/#&togetherjs=OadtjnIqjQ

Comment: jQuery was not defined

Comment: This is what I have my code wrapped around in at the moment. 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

Comment: If you select jQuery at linked jsfiddle by clicking `JAVASCRIPT` the expected result is rendered

Comment: I have selected Language as JaveScript and for Frameworks & Extenstions I have set it to jQuery 1.9.1 and Load Type is onLoad

Comment: Yes, and where both animations occur at jsfiddle when each `<input type="file">` element has `.files` property having a `.length` greater than `0` where either of the `<button>` elements is clicked. What is the issue at linked jsfiddle where jQuery is defined?

Comment: Have a look as now it won't even run the loading animation any more. https://jsfiddle.net/shahz/2j8jfkf5/#&togetherjs=OadtjnIqjQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Included `.length` following`.files` property within `.filter()` function and `.length` property of result of `.filter()`.

Adjusted logic to use two `if` conditions and statements instead of `if..else` at initial `else` statement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #loader1,
    #loader2 {
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font: arial;
      color: #00C853;
      display: none;
    }
    
    #spinner1,
    #spinner2 {
      border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 5px solid #FFA000;
      border-right: 5px solid #00C853;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #FF9933;
      border-left: 5px solid #00C853;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      display: none
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        var input = $("input[type=file]");

        $("[id^=Btn]").click(function() {
          var inputs = $("input[type=file]");

          if (inputs.filter(function(index, el) {
              return el.files.length
            }).length === 2) {
            $("[id^=loader], [id^=spinner]").show();
            $("[id^=Btn]").hide();
          } else {
            if (input.eq(0)[0].files.length && !input.eq(1)[0].files.length) {
              $("[id^=loader]:eq(0), [id^=spinner]:eq(0)").show();
              $("[id^=Btn]:eq(0)").hide();
            }
            if (input.eq(1)[0].files.length && !input.eq(0)[0].files.length) {
              $("[id^=loader]:eq(1), [id^=spinner]:eq(1)").show();
              $("[id^=Btn]:eq(1)").hide();
            }

          }
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="p1" />
  <div id="loader1">
    <div id="spinner1"></div>
    loading</div>
  <button id="Btn1">
    upload
  </button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="file" id="p2" />
  <div id="loader2">
    <div id="spinner2"></div>
    loading</div>
  <button id="Btn2">
    upload
  </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just tested this updated code and even when i just upload in the first field and press the second upload button it runs the loading animation in both input fields even though I had only uploaded a file in the first field.

Comment: `.filter()` function should also return `.length` `if (inputs.filter(function(index, el) {
              return el.files.length
            }).length === 2)` see version 5 at http://plnkr.co/edit/kqwLs8qhq9S3iGzdpipf?p=preview

Comment: I have tested the code again and at the moment it runs the animations on both fields when they have files selected in them and also runs the animation in the first field if there is a file loaded into it regardless which button is pressed BUT when I ONLY upload a file in the second field and click on either of the upload buttons the animation runs in the first field instead of the second field in which the file was actually present.

Comment: _"BUT when I ONLY upload a file in the second field and click on either of the upload buttons the animation runs in the first field instead of the second field in which the file was actually present."_ That was the original requirement, yes? _"My objective is to now show a loading animation in the case above. I.e. show a loading animation around the first choose file button even if the second  upload button was clicked and vice versa."_

Comment: "My objective is to now show a loading animation in the cases above. I.e. show a loading animation around the first choose file button even if the second upload button was clicked and vice versa." I am aiming for both variations as mentioned in the original requirement. By vice versa I meant that if a file is loaded in the second field and the first upload button is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by "both variations"? The requirement is clear that the first `<button>` animation should be run if a file is selected at second `<input>`

Comment: by vice versa in my original requirement it is supposed to mean that scenario be switched i.e. instead of the first upload field it should be the second upload field which has the file in it and the first upload button be clicked and then animation should run in the second upload field as that is the only field with the file in it.

Comment: _"instead of the first upload field it should be the second upload field which has the file in it"_ It is not possible to set a `File` object at `FileList` object of a `<input type="file">` element where `.files` property is read only.

Comment: in short the animation won't run in the second upload field if the file is only uploaded into it and the first upload button is clicked?

Comment: Why would the animation run at the second `<button>` if the first `<input type="file">` element has `.files.length` and first `<button>` is clicked?

Comment: ok there seems to be a confusion. The only scenario which needs to be left answered and is part of the original requirement, is that if the second <input type="file"> element has .files.length and first <button> is clicked then the animation should run around the second <input type="file"> element ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if you convert your IDs to classes. This would handle any number of loading animations for you, and is quite easy to understand as well.

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $(document).on("click", ".UploadBtn", function() {
           $(".p").each(function(file) {
           if ($(this).val()) {
               $(this).next(".loader").show();
               $(this).next(".loader").find(".spinner").show();
               $(this).next(".loader").find(".UploadBtn").hide();
                       }
                   });
               });
       });
```